# What is some prerequisite book that can help me to read "mathematical methods for financial markets"

Tags: reference-request

What is some prerequisite book in mathematics or finance that can help me to read "mathematical methods for financial markets"?

I found a lot of difficulties when try to start to read the PDF of this book.

Comment: Can you post a link to the book which you mean?

Comment: I download it in a chinese finance forum

Comment: @emcor - if you give me your email address, i may send it to you

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Financial-Springer-Textbooks/dp/144712524X

Comment: Chapter 1 of the book actually listed the math prerequisite. If that's still deep, try Shreve's "Stochastic calculus for finance"

Comment: @athos - What else could i looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shreve's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144192311X) can really be thought as "calculus of finance".

If you say there should be pre-calculus or high school mathematics of finance.

[Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133456315) - John C Hull

[A Primer For The Mathematics Of Financial Engineering (Financial Engineering Advanced Background Series)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979757622) - Dan Stefanica

Of course this is from my perspective of derivatives product. Something more for asset pricing, enter [John Cochrane](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chicagobooth.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fdirectory%2Fc%2Fjohn-h-cochrane&ei=LGscVNC5IYTjaIKTgIAK&usg=AFQjCNGJhrxQfu-SJao_oMuAld1EUlG5Yw&sig2=RDyfYKlPY5qCmBzG0U4ttw).

[Book](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7836.html)

[Course page](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/teaching/35904_Asset_Pricing/)

[Coursera class](https://www.coursera.org/course/assetpricing)

There can be better sources but these are also good enough to start with.